# Cross-compiling plugins for multiple DCCs

Tags: c++, maya, haxe

Been using Haxe off and on for a few years, and I feel like this is something the compiler might be abusable for:

Is is possible to add target such that when a Haxe class is compiled, it can introspect the compiled code and generate boilerplate in C++?  An example:

In Autodesk Maya to create a plugin node, you have to have a number of special functions overridden in a child class.  Attributes on the node have to be declared first in the header, then declared statically in the cpp file, and finally added in a particular way (with error checks) in one of the function overrides.  Apart from that, you have to write functions that register and de-register the plugin from the system.  The pattern is just non-trivial enough that simple search / replace isn't good enough; you have to replace text in different patterns in different places, and also add function calls depending on the type of attributes and the attribute's settings.

A node with the same behavior in Foundry's Modo is very different-- you have to define three classes and compose functionality.

In both cases, the way you access data from within the node is also different, so if you were to wrap a single C++ function for both programs you'd be doing a lot of work outside the function just to prep the data in an agnostic way.

I'd like to be able to write a single node using Haxe code and generate C++ code from the Haxe class.  In the case of Maya, it would subclass from MPxNode and provide the proper function overrides.  In the case of Modo, it would generate the required classes properly. And in the future if I wanted to target Cinema 4D, I would add an additional target and compile against that SDK to create its version of the same functionality (probably a Tag).

I've actually done this partly in Python (generating C++ code with stubs for node functionality) and while it works, I've always been curious if there could be a better way to do this through Haxe directly.  But again, it's something where the compiler would have to be aware of the structure of the Haxe class and the data within it in order to generate the proper code for each target.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i would imagine a macro that generated the boiler plate classes is the way to go, tho i dont think you can hook into the generated output of haxe's target inside a macro.

Comment: You should check with the developers behind the [unreal.hx](https://github.com/proletariatgames/unreal.hx) project for ideas, since they have solved more or less a similar issue.

Comment: That's an interesting project-- thanks for the link!